# Использование Android Studio для разработки приложений

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, книги

Воспользуюсь хорошим настроением Хешкодовцев, спрошу нубский вопрос.

В целях заполнить вечернее послерабочее время безделья, коего стало много после окончания игр близов, решил податься далее в самообразование.

Вопрос собственно состоит достаточно абстрактный - решил изучать программирование под android. Скачал разрекламированную студию, прочитал старткнижку лектора МГУ по быстрому старту разработки под адройды... а понимания все еще не появилось. Открываю студию - куча файлов, всяческие конфигурации, ох боже ж ты мой. В общем это как учиться плавать на берегу и тебя бросают с лодки в воду, с криком - ты же все уже прочитал.

- Есть ли дизайнер окон?
- Есть ли дополнительные компоненты визуальные?
- Где привычные из других языков не визуальные компоненты, но все же компоненты, которые можно кинуть на форму и забыть про их создание (ну например таймер, который по тикам будет вызывать события);
- и еще много и много вопросов, но остальное по ходу разбирательства =)

Посоветуйте более-менее полную книжку по андройду. Разрабатывать предполагаю, буду для себя всяческие утилиты для автоматизации своей обыденной деятельности за телефоном и планшетом. Идеи рассказывать не буду, просто если появятся такие же утилиты в гуглплее - у меня пропадет интерес что-то делать.

Если о себе, то с языками программирования знаком с 1997 года, по хронологии: Pascal, delphi7, BDS 2006, c# winforms (3.5), bat/cmd, c# wpf (3.5, 4.0), powershell (2.0), и еще несколько страшных слов.
Java только начинаю понимать на уровне принадлежности к андройд, но как не посмотрю - слова другие, а суть таже.

В общем суть вопроса по интерфейсу студии и ее возможностей (вдруг кто уже освоил новинку) и поиск книжки (можно из серии "быстрый старт" на подобие той что прочитал, можно чуть по глубже). Но для меня быстрое изучение будет только если книга на русском =) увы на английском обучен читать по диагонали, выхватывая только нужные слова, зачастую пропуская нюансы.

Спасибо за терпимость и очередную помощь.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> > Есть ли дизайнер окон?

да. ищите каталоги, которые начинаются с слова `layout`, там xml файлы. Открывайте их и увидите дизайнер (возможно придется внизу переключиться на вкладку "Design".)

> > Есть ли дополнительные компоненты визуальные?

да, например Sherlock ActionBar.

> > Где привычные из других языков не визуальные компоненты, но все же компоненты, которые 
> > можно кинуть на форму и забыть про их создание (ну например таймер, который по тикам будет вызывать события);

такого нет. Их придется ручками в коде создавать. Но часто это всего пару строк. Вообще то невизуальные элемены есть - это всякие LinearLayout/RelativeLayout  - менеджеры компоновок. Но они нужны, что бы размещать правильно элементы.

Что почитать.

Мне очень нравится сайт startandroid.ru - все на русском и достаточно понятно. Живой форум. Да, там на базе эклипса описывается, но это дело достаточно наживное - горячие кнопки другие да цвет иконок.

Также, объязательно следует ходить на сайт d.android.com - там много справочного материала, есть примеры. Такой себе msdn.com, но для андроида и заметно лучше.

Из книг рекомендую поискать из серии Pro Android. И желательно на английском. Потому как в русском часто так переведут, что читать не хочется - "намерение (то есть intent) активировало активность(то есть activity), на которой находиться представление(то есть view)".

Comment: Благодарю за развернутый ответ.